Why is source alpha forced to 1 in my alpha blended R16 RenderTarget?
In my shader, I have a half-precision floating-point variable named DepthAux, which is bound to the first render target (SV_Target1) and has an R16 format. I've enabled alpha blending for this render target.I want to know how the blending of R16's rendertarget is done.  I'm wondering why this is happening and if there are any known issues or limitations with alpha blending on R16 render targets.
when I tested on different machine, I consistently found that the source alpha value is 1.0

Why does source alpha have anything to do with the render target? That comes from your shader. In terms of limitations, some older GPUs do not support blending into float render targets, but nearly all modern hardware does. What GPU are you using?

@solidpixel I mean SV_Target1 is not have alpha channel
layout(location = 0) out mediump vec4 SV_Target0;
layout(location = 1) out mediump float SV_Target1;
I conducted tests on Mali's GPU

Which specific Mali GPU? There are quite a few of them ...

... but if your source alpha is 1 in the shader, then there is no blending - it's opaque.
